# Changing the amount you "tab" java?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, joptionpane

As above. I have a modal JOptionPane that uses a text area to display a slightly larger than normal message. The Pane works fine and is currently roughly 300px sq. The problem is I am trying to output something similar to the following:

```
Amt (TAB HERE) x (TAB HERE) Type (TAB HERE) Price (TAB HERE)
```

Again I have no problem with the actual Panel at all it's displaying at the size I want but for some reason it "tabs" really far. Like 1/3 of the JOptionPane such that it cuts off after Type and I lose half my text. Is there any way I can specify the size of the tab I want? I've tried aligning manually using spaces but as you can imagine not all letters are the same width and it's just too damn hard to get it to line up properly so I NEED to tab. I don't want to mess around with new layout managers either. I am simply concatonating a string in a method returning it to a JTextArea and then putting that inside my JOptionPane so I'd like a solution that works doing this. If I output to the command line the tab looks normal, like maybe 5 odd characters but doing that in this manner it's more like 2 words long....

Worse case scenario I make a bigger JOptionPane but I would prefer not to for aesthetics.

Comment: This happens in `TextLayout`, specifically in `LineBreakMeasurer` but I don't know where `JOptionPane` configures it.

Comment: please your question(s) is / are ???, best of ways could be to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an HTML table in your `JTextArea` like they show [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). Either a `JTextArea` or a `JTable` can go in a `JOptionPane`.